# Python: list.index fails to find existing element

Tags: python, list

Can someone explain to me how the funcion list.index() functions? I have the following code:

```
def getPos(self,tile):
        print self.tiles[5][5]
        print tile
        try:
           myIndex = self.tiles.index(tile)
           #some code
        except:
           print "exception raised"
           #some code
```

The result:

```
<Tile.Tile instance at 0x36BCEB8>
<Tile.Tile instance at 0x36BCEB8>
exception raised
```

Do you have an idea why list.index() returns an exception although the tile variable is a reference to an element of tiles[][] ? Thanks a lot.

ps: btw I'm passing tiles[5][5] in this specific case

Comment: As an aside: Never use a bare `except:` - always be specific in what exceptions you want to catch, or you might catch some that you are not expecting.

Comment: Think about this for a minute. If `some_list.index(some_item)` returns `i`, then `some_list[i]` should return `some_item`. What are you expecting `myIndex` to be after your `index` call? If it's going to work, you'd need to be able to say `self.tiles[myIndex]`. But there's obviously no possible thing that `myIndex` could be to make that work. So `self.tile.index(tile)` can't be expected to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the element does exist, it is not directly a member of `tiles`:

- `tiles` is a two-dimensional list (a list of lists).
- `tiles[5]` is a list of `Tile`s.
- `tiles[5][5]` is a single `Tile`.

Python does not recursively descend into a multidimensional list to find the element you're looking for. Therefore `tiles.index(tile)` fails; `tiles[5].index(tile)` would work.

To illustrate:

```
>>> l = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> l.index(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 4 is not in list
>>> l[1].index(4)
1
```

Answer (score 4):

`self.tiles` appears to be a sequence (e.g. list or tuple) of sequences. 
Elements of `self.tiles` are sequences, not tiles.

`self.tiles.index(tile)` tries to find a sequence which equals `tile`, and fails.

Try instead:

```
def getPos(self,tile):
    for i,row in enumerate(self.tiles):
        for j,elt in enumerate(row):
            if tile == elt:
                return (i,j)
    raise ValueError('no tile found')
```

Comment: It works too but it's a little less efficient than Tim Pietzcker's solution. Thanks though.

Comment: If you use `.index` then every time the tile is not in the row, a ValueError will the raised. To cycle through all the rows, you'll have to use `try...except`. When you expect lots of exceptions to be raised, using `if` tends to be faster than `try..except`.

Answer (score -1):

How come tiles[5][5] and tile points to the same instance?  It appears to me that you grab entire this object at tile[5][5] as tile and try to locate it as an element of it.  dont understand your intention

Comment: sorry that i didt have answer, but i thought my observation leads to resolve cause of trouble.  maybe it was some my misunderstanding of issue.